# How to solve Android studio api 26 missing error

Tags: android, android-studio

I had already installed API 26 in android studio but I still get error when I click on object method for more information about class and method it contained:
[image: here is the image of my error]
[image: here is the image of my setting]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, kindly read this post here which is regarding how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask